# Ajax and Spring MVC view list in a table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

I am new to ajax. I am using spring mvc, hibernate and Ajax. My ajax is able to persist to DB but to view the list in the table is not working. Could anyone help me on that. Below is the code snippet:

Once the user click on create button (
      Create New Customer) Then a modal dialog opens and the user is asked to put name and age. Once the create button with in the modal is clicked it calls the ajax function and i see the value gets persisted to DB but am not able to get the list with in the table.

my JSP(ajaxExmpl):

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjaxPost() {
        // get the form values
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "createP",
            data : "name=" + name + "&age=" + age,
            success : function(response) {
                // we have the response
                alert('data saved to DB');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar-inner">



    </div>
      <a href="#" class="createCustomer" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#createCustomerModal">Create New Customer</a>

<!-- Table to view the list saved in database -->

    <section class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>Person List</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <c:forEach var="person" items="${persons}" varStatus="status">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${status.count}" /></td>
                            <td>${person.name}</td>
                            <td>${person.age}</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        Actions <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a>Edit</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="delete/${person.id}">Delete</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                <tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>



    <!-- All modal dialog goes below this line -->


    <!--create customer modal  -->



    <div id="createCustomerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">


            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Create New Customer
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">



                    <table class="form-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                    class="not-required" for="pool-name">Name:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                    class="not-required" for="expire-after">Age:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="age" class="form-control" /></td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="createNewCustomer"
                            onclick="doAjaxPost();" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createP", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(Person person, Model model) {
    personService.addPerson(person);
    return "redirect:/listP";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/listP", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String listPerson(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("persons", personService.getAllPersons());
    return "ajaxExmpl";

}
```

Comment: Do you see 'data saved to DB' alert and did page refresh as you have given "redirect:/listP" in the  addPerson person call? My understanding is since you are giving Ajax call so no page refresh is happening, since page refresh is not happening so you are not seeing the latest data in the table.

Comment: Yes i see data saved to DB and the alert as well..after i click ok on the alert i see nothing get listed in the page., no page is getting refreshed

Comment: and did you page refresh in the browser?

Comment: no not at all...no page refresh

Comment: Since you are making Ajax call it was not refreshing the page hence you new model attribute is not getting loaded. You need to do partial refresh or full page refresh in success function. For full refresh, In success method try to refresh your jsp by putting window.location = '/app/ajaxExmpl url'.

Comment: i did the refresh by putting window.location='/CRUDWebUI/listP' in success function and it worked...thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it worked, let me post it as answer so that you can mark this answer as closed, will this work for you?

Comment: Yes...please go ahead.

Comment: I have created Address object and it has OneToOne relationship with User object, How can i put that in my ajax and jsp code. If anyone knows. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making Ajax call it was not refreshing the page hence you new model attribute is not getting loaded. You need to do partial refresh or full page refresh in success function. For full refresh, In success method try to refresh your jsp by putting `window.location = '/CRUDWebUI/listP'`