# Ajax and Spring MVC data not getting populated on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

i have asked a question regarding not able to list data in a table with ajax in this link: [Ajax and Spring MVC view list in a table not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085191/ajax-and-spring-mvc-view-list-in-a-table-not-working/46101968#46101968)

The above issue was resolved now am trying to use Address object with in a Customer object with OneToOne relationship, how do i put that in my ajax and jsp code. The issue here is that the address values like street,state,zipCode...not getting saved to DB after clicking the create button, Only the customer details like customerName, email are getting populated. If there is anyone who can help. Thanks.Below is the code snippet:-

script.js

```
function doAjaxPosts() {
// get the form values

var customerName= $('#customerName').val();
var contactName= $('#contactName').val();
var email= $('#email').val();
var street= $('#street').val();
var zipCode= $('#zipCode').val();
var state= $('#state').val();
var country= $('#country').val();

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :  "createCustomer",
    data: "customerName="+ customerName + "&contactName=" + contactName + "&email=" + email + "&street=" + street +
          "&state=" + state + "&zipCode=" + zipCode + "&country=" + country,

    success : function(response) {
        // we have the response
        alert('data saved to DB');
        window.location = '/UtilityWebApplication'
    }
});
```

}

My methods in my Controller class:

//this is the default home page

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goToHomePage(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("customers", customerServiceImpl.getAllCustomers());
        return "Home";

    }

    //Method to Create Customer 
    @RequestMapping(value="/createCustomer", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createCustomer(Customer customer, Model model) {
        customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        customer.setCustomerDeleted(false);
        customerServiceImpl.createCustomer(customer);
        model.addAttribute("customers", customerServiceImpl.getAllCustomers());
        return "Home";

    }
```

jsp page:

```
<!--create customer modal  -->

<div id="createCustomerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Create New Customer
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">



                <table class="form-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="pool-name">Customer Name:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="customerName" title="Company Name" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Contact Name:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="contactName" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="description">Street:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="street" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">State:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="state" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Zip-Code:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="zipCode" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Country:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="country" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Email:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="email" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" id="createNewCustomer" value="Create"
                        class="btn btn-default" onClick="doAjaxPosts();" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Customer Class:

```
 import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String customerName;
    private String contactName;
    private String email;


    private Boolean customerDeleted= false;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval= true)
    private List<Certificate> certificates;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    private Address address;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date deletedDate;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;
    private String street;
    private String state; 
    private int zipCode;
    private String country;

    public Customer() {

    }



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Certificate> getCertificates() {
        return certificates;
    }

    public void setCertificates(List<Certificate> certificates) {
        this.certificates = certificates;
    }

    public Boolean getCustomerDeleted() {
        return customerDeleted;
    }

    public void setCustomerDeleted(Boolean customerDeleted) {

        this.customerDeleted = customerDeleted;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Date getDeletedDate() {
        return deletedDate;
    }

    public void setDeletedDate(Date deletedDate) {
        this.deletedDate = deletedDate;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {

        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
}
```

Address Class:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String street;
    private String state; 
    private int zipCode;
    private String country;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy="address", orphanRemoval=true)
    private Customer customer;

    public Address() {}
    public Address(String street,String state,int zipCode,String country) {
        this.street=street;
        this.state=state;
        this.zipCode=zipCode;
        this.country=country;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    }
```

CustomerDaoImp Class only the CreatePart:

```
    @Override
    public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(customer);

    }
```

CustomerServiceImp Class:

```
@Override
    public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {


        customerDao.createCustomer(customer);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending an object in ajax data parameter, object keys should be the same as your customer model properties names in spring, if it still not work then try creating a new instance of type Address in your service and set it to your customer object before saving customer

```
  $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url :  "createCustomer",
        data: {customerName: customerName, contactName: contactName, email: email, address: {
      street: street, zipCode: zipCode, country: country
    }}
        success : function(response) {
            // we have the response
            alert('data saved to DB');
            window.location = '/UtilityWebApplication'
        }
    });


        //Method to Create Customer 
                @RequestMapping(value="/createCustomer", method=RequestMethod.POST)
                public String createCustomer(@Requestbody Customer customer, Model model) {
                    customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                    customer.setCustomerDeleted(false);
                    customerServiceImpl.createCustomer(customer);
                    model.addAttribute("customers", customerServiceImpl.getAllCustomers());
                    return "Home";

                }



@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Column
    private String country;

    @Column
    private int zipCode;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Customer customer;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}

@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: i used the code you suggested on ajax and i am getting such error: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'address[country]' of bean class [com.model.Customer]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'address[country]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [usa]

Comment: I've suggested 2 solutions 1 in client side and an other one in server side. Have you tried both? can you post your customer entity and address entity?

Comment: Your customer entity should have Address entity as a property with @OneToOne realationship annotation

Comment: I have posted all, the models and the service class as well. I tried your second suggestion as well but i got same error. could you please add your second suggestion on above code if possible thanks.